# Capturing Table Data From Redirected URL In Java / Android

Tags: java, android, response.redirect, http-redirect, redirect

Ok. So I'm trying to access some public records which exist online and import them into Android. They currently exist as a publicly available web service which returns an HTML page containing a table which I pull into my app using jSoup which contains a link to another page which contains the actual data I would like to scrape. Thus far I have built a scraper which can scrape data off the 1st HTML page, extract it from the table and display it as textview01. What I need to do on top of this is follow that link and display the redirected page's data in textview02.

I understand this is a both simple and difficult at the same time - any help is greatly appreciated!

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    String url = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=AARON&fname=";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();

        }

                   private Document manualRedirectHandler(String url) throws IOException{
                        Response response = Jsoup.connect(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).followRedirects(false).execute();
                        int status = response.statusCode();

                    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                    {
                        String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
                        System.out.println("Redirect to: " + redirectUrl);//key will be here
                        return manualRedirectHandler(redirectUrl);
                    }

                    return Jsoup.parse(response.body());
                    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            {
                try {


                    manualRedirectHandler(url);

                    String imageURL = "http://exampleurl.com/icon.jpg"; // this needs to display the user's image from the redirected page
                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() > 0) {
                            title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                                    + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(3).text();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);
           // tv2.setText(title2); - this needs work - I need to update this textview with the table data from the URL obtained after redirect

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT AFTER FIRST RESPONSE/ANSWER:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    String url = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=hello&fname=";
    String tr;
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("lname", "LastNameFromUser").data("firstname","fname").post();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();

        }

                   private Document manualRedirectHandler(String url) throws IOException{
                        Response response = Jsoup.connect(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).followRedirects(false).execute();
                        int status = response.statusCode();

                    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                    {
                        String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
                        System.out.println("Redirect to: " + redirectUrl);//key will be here
                        return manualRedirectHandler(redirectUrl);
                    }

                    return Jsoup.parse(response.body());
                    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            {
                try {


                    manualRedirectHandler(url);

                    String imageURL = "http://exampleurl.com/icon.jpg"; // this needs to display the user's image from the redirected page
                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() > 0) {
                            title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                                    + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(3).text();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);
           // tv2.setText(title2); - this needs work - I need to update this textview with the table data from the URL obtained after redirect

        }

    }
}
```

RESULTS:

"Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor" on the line:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("lname", "LastNameFromUser").data("firstname","fname").post();
```

Comment: "EDIT AFTER FIRST RESPONSE" <p> Don't role your own Internet connections. Use my library here: https://github.com/horvste/EasyWebPageDownloadForAndroid

Answer (score 0):

I have created something like this here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.search.wisconsinccap&hl=en

To do this you are going to need to do something similar to this.

```
/*Assuming you are using post()*/
    String url = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=hello&fname=";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("lname", "LastNameFromUser").data("fname","FirstNameFromUser").post();
```

EDIT
Retry above code snip bit. You could also just construct the URL and then connect to that URL.

THIS CODE IS WORKING:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SheriffParser {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public static final String URL = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?";

    public SheriffParser(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Elements fillOutForm() throws IOException {
        return Jsoup.connect(this.URL).data("lname", this.lastName)
                .data("fname", this.firstName).post().select("tbody");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?";
    SheriffParser parser = new SheriffParser("InsertFirstName","InsertLastName");
    System.out.println(parser.fillOutForm().toString());
}
```

}

This will get you the table, then you use a parsing algorithm to seperate the categories. You should create another class with Arrest No.,Name,Sex,Location as Parameters.

Please consider breaking up your Activity into multiple classes and using better naming conventions. This would make you be able to diagnose errors better and also make the code more readable.